# IntelliJ - Can i cut & paste an entire class in?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes I want to paste an entire class in.

I don't really want to remember the class name - remembering is tricky!

In IntelliJ, it's easy to make a new java file - but then the class name has to match the name of the thing I'm pasting in!

IntelliJ is smart enough to, when I past code in, fix the package.

Can I somehow paste the code in so IntelliJ will also rename the file to match the public class file name?

Comment: You can copy/paste the file itself. **Update**: then, refactor the class in the new file to the new name

Comment: Use Refactor | Copy on the class. It will prompt you for the name of the class and create a new class with the correct name in the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

After pasting your class, the class name should be underlined red.

You can put the cursor/caret on it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You'll get possible fixes: rename file or rename class.

Select the one to rename class.